# Can't cast 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject' to actual type

Tags: c#, json, linq, deserialization

I have the following code for getting a response from my server. I can deserialize the response to my ApiResponse object type, but I can't cast an inner object to it's real type.

Here is where I am getting the response from the server:

```
var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
    var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
    GlobalTestVariables.Response = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ApiResponse>(result);
    var a = GlobalTestVariables.Response.Result as TokenModel; // a = null
}
```

The value of `var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();` is as follows:

```
var result = "{\"IsSuccess\":true,\"Message\":\"Login Successful\",\"Result\":{\"id_token\":\"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6InBsaW10ZXN0aW5nIiwibmJmIjoxNTE1MDc5NzMyLCJleHAiOjE1MTUwODA5MzIsImlhdCI6MTUxNTA3OTczMn0.wcr5zndSwdrDL7huea_oWpAl8ohL0GL3NZOmc_VBduc\"},\"Status\":200}"
```

This is what's being returned:

```
return new ApiResponse(true, HttpStatusCode.OK, "Login Successful", new TokenModel(JwtManager.GenerateToken(user.Username)));
```

Where ApiResponse is:

```
[DataContract]
public class ApiResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Message { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public Object Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public ApiResponse() { }

    public ApiResponse(bool isSuccess, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message = null, object result = null)
    {
        IsSuccess = isSuccess;
        Status = (int)statusCode;
        Result = result;
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

And TokenModel is:

```
public class TokenModel
{
    public string id_token { get; set; }
    public TokenModel(string token)
    {
        this.id_token = token;
    }
    public TokenModel() { }
}
```

Does anybody know how to deserialize it to it's correct type?

Comment: Can't you change `Result` type to `TokenModel`? Is the type of `Result` known at compile-time? Post a sample of a JSON response.

Comment: @NicodeOry I have updated the original post to include the value of `result`

Answer (score 0):

There are two options:

1. You change the type of `ApiResponse.Result` to `TokenModel`. The deserializer then expects a `TokenModel` and will deserialize it appropriately.
2. If the type of the property `Result` is dynamic, you need to include type information in the serialized JSON string. For that, have a look at the [TypeNameHandling](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeTypeNameHandling.htm) setting.

Comment: Result is dynamic and could be any type of custom object model. I'll check out that link now thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As long as `Result` always has `id_token` in the JSON, it's as simple as changing `Result` to `TokenModel`.

```
    [DataContract]
public class ApiResponse
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool IsSuccess { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public String Message { get; set; }
    [DataMember(EmitDefaultValue = false)]
    public TokenModel Result { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public int Status { get; set; }

    public ApiResponse() { }

    public ApiResponse(bool isSuccess, HttpStatusCode statusCode, string message = null, TokenModel result = null)
    {
        IsSuccess = isSuccess;
        Status = (int)statusCode;
        Result = result;
        Message = message;
    }
}
```

Comment: Result could be any type of object, not just a token model.

Comment: My bad, I thought it was always `TokenModel`, from the sample JSON. In that case take a look at option 2 of Oliver's answer, or check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13683757/newtonsoft-json-dynamic-objects). Maybe you could do `dynamic result = JObject.Parse(resultJSON);`